# In a Makefile, how do I define wildcard patterns?

Tags: makefile, wildcard, gnu-make

My directory has many files with similar names: test1.cpp, test2.cpp, test3.cpp, etc. I want to compile all test files into executables test1, test2, test3, etc. They don't have to be linked to each other.

```
CC  = clang++
CXX = clang++

INCLUDES =

CFLAGS   = -g -Wall $(INCLUDES)
CXXFLAGS = -g -Wall $(INCLUDES)

LDFLAGS = -g
LDLIBS  =

.PHONY: default
default: test1 test2

test1:

test2:
```

Instead of specifying test1, test2, I want to use wildcards or pattern matching or something along those lines. How do I do this?

Comment: I suggest reading the [Make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html), and searching for "wildcard" ;)

Comment: Uhm... a simple answer is not using a makefile, but rather defining the variables in the environment and then using the implicit make rules: `make test1`, if there is a `test1.cpp` file in the directory (and no makefile) will run the compiler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

David Rodgriquez has the right idea: `make` has built-in rules that will handle this for you.  However I would recommend using a makefile rather than setting variables in your environment, so you can easily perform the build as another user etc. where the environment is not set up properly.  Also you can use a makefile to create the `default` target.

This is good enough:

```
CC  = clang++
CXX = clang++

INCLUDES =

CFLAGS   = -g -Wall $(INCLUDES)
CXXFLAGS = -g -Wall $(INCLUDES)

LDFLAGS = -g
LDLIBS  =

.PHONY: default
default: $(basename $(wildcard test*.cpp))
```

That's all you need!

Comment: Thanks. How would I create a clean for this though? Executables don't have a convenient extension to identify them.

Comment: It should be quite straightforward for you to figure out how to extend my example to work with a clean rule: the function sequence `$(basename $(wildcard test*.cpp))` gets you the names of all the executables, so you can just delete them.

Comment: An executable would be named something like "test1", "test2", etc. I would need something like $(basename $(wildcard test* <I need to add some option to ignore files with a .cpp or .o here>))

Comment: You should just try it.  `$(wildcard test*.cpp)` will expand to all the `.cpp` files.  Then the `$(basename ...)` will remove the `.cpp` extension, leaving just `test1`, `test2`, etc. with no extension at all.  If you remove them with `rm -f` then it will forcibly remove the files and not complain if they don't exist.  That's what you said you had and what you wanted to build.  If there's more than that, you need to reflect that in your question.